# Storage data move from Google Cloud to Azure

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to Storage data move from Google Cloud to Azure,actually, I want to move data from google cloud to azure Storage without changes there their key and another thing.because I have a relation with this into the database.
Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you mean by `without changes there their key and other thing`?

Comment: Do you mean "no changes to the data of the object" or do you mean "I want the path to access the object to be the same" or do you mean "I want the object name part to stay the same"? The first is easy, the second is not possible, the third depends on how you named your objects. Provide more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Skyplane](https://github.com/skyplane-project/skyplane) to move data across clouds with a simple CLI command. Run `skyplane init` to authenticate with both Google Cloud and Azure. Then, to  move data from Google Cloud to Azure, you can use the command:

```
skyplane cp -r azure://azure-bucket-name/ gcs://gc-bucket-name/
```